# Build my own dataset to use with Tensorflow or Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

Currently I load my dataset this way:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

But I would like to use my own dataset that is labeled in folders this way:

```
flower_phoyos/daisy 
flower_phoyos/dandelion
flower_phoyos/roses
flower_phoyos/sunflowers
flower_phoyos/tulips
```

Each subfolder is a class to be classified, the classifier must sort daisy, dandelion, roses, sunflowers ou tulips.

The solution can be with tensorflow or keras

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant method, but for a small dataset this should be sufficient. 
First get a list of all of the files, and note their classes:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

file_list = []
class_list = []

classnames = ['daisy', 'dandelion', 'roses', 'sunflowers', 'tulips']   
for class_name in classnames:
    dir_list = os.listdir(os.path.join('flower_phoyos', class_name))
    file_list.extend(dir_list)
    class_list.extend([classnames] * len(dir_list))
```

Now you know how many examples you have (`len(file_list)`) and can read them in, assigning them to a numpy array.

```
img_data = np.zeros(len(file_list), height, width, n_bands)
# Of course I've assumed that you want all of the images to be the same size.
for ii, file_ in enumerate(file_list):
    img = plt.imread(file_)
    # Resize to height, width if your images are not all the same size.
    img_data[ii, :, :, :] = img
class_labels = np.array(class_list)
```

You can now reorder your img_data and class_labels (making sure you reorder them in the same way) and split them into train and test.